# C preprocessor macro for filling out struct fields

Tags: c, gcc, struct, macros

Say I have some structs:

```
struct mything1 {
   int foo;
   int has_foo;

   int bar;
   int has_bar
};
```

I'd like to write a macro that does something like

```
#define FILL(instance, field, value)    \
do {                                    \
    instance.#field = value;            \
    instance.has_#field = 1;            \
} while(0);                             \
```

so that I can just go `struct mything1 x; FILL(x, foo, 5);` but this does not work when I try to compile it. Is this possible somehow? Is it advicable?

GCC specific, non-portable solutions are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are stringifying `field` into `"field"` instead of referring to the field by its identifier. Note that token concatenation is done with `##`, and not `#`. A small fix:

```
#define FILL(instance, field, value)    \
do {                                    \
    instance.field = value;             \
    instance.has_##field = 1;           \
} while(0)
```

I also removed the semi-colon after the `while(0)`. The idiom is designed to make `FILL(x, foo, 5);` work by having the semi-colon following the use of the macro complete the statement. Otherwise you just end up with a trailing empty statement that can raise warnings.

Comment: @user7893856 Please note that the do-while(0) trick in macros are only useful for people who don't use braces consistently. If you always use `{ }` after every single if/else/for/while, then the do-while(0) trick is obsolete. If you think not using braces is a great idea, consider that one of the most expensive bugs in programming history, "the Apple goto-fail bug", was created by programmers who didn't use braces.

Answer (score 1):

This is an "XY problem". There is no reason to use a macro, that's just plain obfuscation. Don't do this.

Instead, simply use designated initializers:

```
struct mything1 x = 
{
  .foo = 5
};
```

If you want "has_foo" to be set at the same time, consider solving this with proper design:

```
typedef struct
{
  int  value;
  bool exists;
} thing_t;

typedef struct
{
  thing_t foo;
  thing_t bar;
} many_things_t;

many_things_t things = 
{
  .foo = {5, true}
};
```

---

As the very last resort, if you are truly stuck with the struct and you truly *must* have a macro instead of a function, for reasons unknown, then at least use a standard convention for how to write such macros.

In this case, it would probably be wise to use "X macros", as those are designed for avoiding code repetition. You can make a list of field names and initializers:

```
#define THING_LIST \
  X(foo, 5)        \
  X(bar, 7)
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mything1 {
   int foo;
   int has_foo;

   int bar;
   int has_bar;
};

#define THING_LIST \
  X(foo, 5)        \
  X(bar, 7)  

int main() 
{
  struct mything1 thing = 
  {
    #define X(field, value) \
      .field = value,       \
      .has_##field = 1,
    THING_LIST
    #undef X
  };

  printf("foo: %d has_foo: %d\n", thing.foo, thing.has_foo);
  printf("bar: %d has_bar: %d\n", thing.bar, thing.has_bar);
}
```

Comment: I didn't design the struct with the foo, has_foo fields though, I'm trying to make a user-friendly wrapper around protobuf-c, which generates these structs for you. So I'm stuck with what I've got.

Comment: Also, I think it's great that so many stackexchange answers points out when you're doing something ill-adviced. But there seems to be a common theme permeating these answers, and that's not explaining why it is ill-adviced. A simple link to somewhere it is explained would suffice.

Comment: @user7893856 There are many reasons why you should avoid function-like macros. In this case, you should ironically avoid them for the sake of user-friendliness. You can expect a C programmer to understand what a initializer list does (with or without designated initializers). You can expect a C programmer to understand what a function such as `things_init(&things, value_x, value_y)` does. But you can't expect them to understand what `struct thing_t things; MAGIC_MACRO(things, value_x_, value_y)` does.

Comment: The two former are convention, the last one is an attempt to re-design the C language and replace it with your own home-brewed, secret, most-likely-poorly-documented macro language. C programmers know how C works. They do not know how the secret marco language works.

Comment: In general, I'd be inclined to agree. But if fields gets added to the protocol specification (as frequently happens), then one would have to rewrite all the initializers to accomodate them. It would be nasty.

Comment: @user7893856 I added an "icky macro alternative" that is at least somewhat industry standard for how to write icky macros, namely "X macros". They are useful for maintenance purposes when you can't re-design the program. Only use it as the very last resort.